# create new issue in jira

Tags: java, jira

i want to know which libraries i need to import and from where to get them
in order to create new issue in java?
thanx

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Appendix+A+-+Extending+JIRA) is the link to the JIRA Java API, and the related libraries to use. The libraries are available directly from [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Plugin+Development+Kit). Note the comment at the top of this page relating to Maven repositories. THat may be a simpler option depending on the version of JIRA you're using.